# Solving for x Algebraically

Tags: trigonometry

So my problem is:

$$\arcsin (x) = \arccos (5/13)$$

**^ Solve for $x$.**

How would I begin this problem? Do I draw a triangle and find the $\sin(x)$ or is there a more algebraic way of doing this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can entirely rule out the strategy of "finding the sin of $x$" by thinking heuristically like this: The *input* of sin is an angle and the *output* of sin is a number. Taking inverse functions, the *input* of arcsin is a number and the *output* is an angle. Since $x$ represents the input of arcsin, it represents a number, and and you should not take its sin.

Comment: Draw a right triangle, hypotenuse $13$, one leg $5$. Identify the angle whose cosine is $\frac{5}{13}$. Find its sine.

Comment: Is the answer 12/13?

Comment: You got it ! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\arccos\frac5{13}=\arcsin x=\theta\implies x=\sin\theta,\cos\theta=\frac5{13}$

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $0<\theta<\dfrac\pi2\implies\sin\theta>0$

Use $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$

Answer (score 1):

You do draw a triangle, but "$x$" does not represent something on that triangle that you would take the sin of. Think instead of what $\arcsin(x)$ represents: it is an angle of the triangle. So, assign an angle variable $\theta = \arcsin(x)$. Your job, if you decide to accept it, is to evaluate the angle $\theta$.

Draw a right triangle. Assign one of its angles (not the right angle) to be $\theta$. Assign letters for its side lengths. Write out the equation for the Pythagorean formula of a right triangle using your letters for side lengths.

You are told that $\theta = \arcsin(x)$, so $\sin(\theta)=x$. Hence the ratio $opposite/hypotenuse$ equals $x$. Write out that equation using your letters for side lengths.

You are also told that $\theta = \arccos(5/13)$, so $\cos(\theta) = 5/13$, hence the ratio $adjacent / hypotenuse$ equals $5/13$. Write out that equation using your letters for side lengths.

Now you have a bunch of equations, and you should be able to eliminate all the other variables (the side lengths) and solve the equations for $\theta$.